# Change the names of Vector3 List elements

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Is there a way in Unity to change the name of List elements in the inspector. That is, instead of element 01, 02, etc.

I have created a `NamedListAttribute`:

```
public class NamedListAttribute: PropertyAttribute
{
    public readonly string[] names;
    public NamedListAttribute(string[] names) { this.names = names; }
}
```

Then I created an editor script `NamedListDrawer` to reflect the names on my main script:

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEditor;
 
[CustomPropertyDrawer (typeof(NamedArrayAttribute))]
public class NamedListDrawer: PropertyDrawer
{
    public override void OnGUI(Rect rect, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
    {
        try {
            int pos = int.Parse(property.propertyPath.Split('[', ']')[1]);
            EditorGUI.ObjectField(rect, property, new GUIContent(((NamedListAttribute)attribute).names[pos]));
        } catch {
            EditorGUI.ObjectField(rect, property, label);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally referencing it here in my main script:

```
[NamedListAttribute(new string[] {"Obj_1", "Obj_2", "Obj_3"})]
public List<Vector3> Pos_of_Objs = new List<Vector3> ();
```

Problem is that the names are changing but they are no longer vector3 properties. So how do I set them to be Vector3?

Comment: Maybe this is what you're looking for https://answers.unity.com/questions/1487864/change-a-variable-name-only-on-the-inspector.html

Comment: What names? Where should they come from? Yes you need a custom editor / property drawer / attribute drawer for this. Unfortunately your question is to broad for this community as it is not for requesting full solutions but rather for question about a specific implementation issue  .. if you don't have any implementation yet then this would be off-topic due to asking for a library, tool or tutorial

Comment: @derHugo I have posted the whole code of what I have done so far.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works perfectly fine for me with one little exception:

You are actually getting an exception (which you should have added to the question - would have solved things faster ;) )

> type is not a supported pptr value
>
> UnityEditor.EditorGUI:ObjectField(Rect, SerializedProperty, GUIContent)
>
> NamedListDrawer:OnGUI(Rect, SerializedProperty, GUIContent)

An [`ObjectField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.ObjectField.html) is a reference field for a type derived from [`UnityEngine.Object`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Object.html) like e.g. prefabs, `GameObject`, any `Component` or `MonoBehaviour`, `Texture`, `ScriptableObject` etc.

That happens because you simply copied the code from [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/how-to-change-the-name-of-list-elements-in-the-inspector.448910/#post-2904879) where it was used for `Texture` assets.

---

What you rather wanted to use here would be a [`PropertyField`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/EditorGUI.PropertyField.html) which automatically chooses the correct drawer according to the property's type.

Additionally I would also pass in `true` to `includeChildren` in order to make your property drawer also be able to draw this fields for further nested custom types

```
public override void OnGUI(Rect rect, SerializedProperty property, GUIContent label)
{
    try {
        int pos = int.Parse(property.propertyPath.Split('[', ']')[1]);
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property, new GUIContent(((NamedListAttribute)attribute).names[pos]), true);
    } catch {
        EditorGUI.PropertyField(rect, property, label, true);
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

---

Note however: This might be working for most of things you want to do, you will note though that in cases that the Inspector becomes thinner you might get overlapping fields.